# Error: "Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]"

Tags: updates, repository, software-sources

Here is my `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                       
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease                      
Ign:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease                       
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Hit:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release                         
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                       
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                      
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]                 
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [179 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [122 kB]
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages                     
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1,019 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Err:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB] 
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB] 
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]
Ign:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages
Ign:75 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:76 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages
Ign:77 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:78 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages
Ign:75 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:76 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages
Ign:77 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:78 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages
Ign:75 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:76 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages
Ign:77 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:78 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:75 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:76 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages
Ign:77 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:78 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Fetched 414 kB in 3s (161 kB/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
(logging) bobv@bobv-ubuntu:/etc/apt$ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'i386' currently in use by the database
```

And here is how my `sources.list` looks like:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf` fixed the issue

Comment: instead of posting in comments, do post in answer section. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do the following, and it should fix the issue:

`sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf`